# Catch all signals that would stop a program

Tags: c, signals, sigint, sigterm

I've got a program to catch any terminating signals. Currently all it does is catch <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>. I want to be able to catch <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + \</kbd> in addition to <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>. Here's part of my code.

```
if (signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN) == SIG_ERR)
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: Can't catch SIGINT\n");

if (signal(SIGTERM, SIG_IGN) == SIG_ERR)
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: Can't catch SIGTERM\n");

// do stuff
```

What other signals to I need to implement to catch <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + \</kbd>? And what raises `SIGTERM`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: IIRC, Ctrl+Z raises SIGTSTP, and Ctrl+\ raises SIGQUIT

Comment: You can't catch SIGKILL or SIGSTOP.

Comment: @immibis if you put that in an answer I'll accept it. It works perfectly

Comment: The man page for `signal(2)` lists all the standard signals and what their default actions are. You can see which ones terminate the process in that list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> raises SIGTSTP. <kbd>Ctrl+\</kbd> raises SIGQUIT.

I don't know of any key combination that raises SIGTERM, but of course you can send it using `kill -TERM <pid>` replacing `<pid>` with the process ID. (Or just `kill <pid>`; SIGTERM is the default signal for `kill`)

Note that you can't catch SIGSTOP nor SIGKILL.

Comment: `SIGTERM` is the default signal that kill sends when you don't specify one explicitly.  Its the general "request to exit" signal used by the system, eg, when shutting down, or oversubscribed or some other problem where processes need to be killed.